# Rails 4/Mongoid can't post array

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I've got this as my mongoid doc:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("52eec35e6b65762732000000"),
  draftees: [
    "52e93c266b657641d5000000",
    "52e96a676b6576431d010000",
    "tom"
  ],
  user_id: "52eac4d16b657603d8010000"
}
```

When I try to update via ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/draft_lists",
  data: {"draft_list":{
    "draftees":["bill", "bob", "zeak"]}
},
  success: function(){ 
    alert('success!');
  },
  error: function(){
    alert('error!');
  }
})
```

This does nothing.

I've been struggling with how to format the draftees array so that it'll update the db, but to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

*Note*: Ajax request is via firebug console. Works when my model type for draftees is "String", but not "Array"...so I know ajax request is working.
Controller:

```
  def index
    @players = Player.all
    @draft_lists = DraftList.where(user_id: current_user._id)
  end
  def create
    #If user's draft doesn't exist, create their draft. If it does, update to their preference, based on current_user._id

    draft_list = DraftList.find_or_initialize_by(user_id: current_user._id)
    draft_list.update(draft_list_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @draft_list.save
        format.html { redirect_to @draft_list, notice: 'Draft list was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @draft_list }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @draft_list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: how about showing us the controller that handles the request?

Comment: `draft_list_params` initialization? does you request produce any errors

Comment: Ya, 500 error, but it (before array, using string) will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it's an issue with strong parameters in Rails 4. I needed to permit:

```
def draft_list_params
  params.require(:draft_list).permit(:user_id, :draftees => [])
end
```